# php ssh2 connect to localhost

Tags: php, ssh

i would try use ssh2 to menage my ubuntu system at localhost, if will work fine i will try menage throught net connection. But at first step i have problem to connect to myself on localhost

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
```

result

```
 Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to localhost on port 22 in /var/www/system/index.php on line 6

 Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to localhost in /var/www/system/index.php on line 6
```

meaby i need to do something else??

Comment: Show us your PHP code.

Comment: Are you sure you're running an SSH server on your local system? What happens if you do `ssh localhost` from the shell?

Comment: @JustinWood What other code do you need to see? That line isn't dependent on anything else.

Comment: from shell                    ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Comment: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host